# Redirect output of just one command to different file than rest of script

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

I have a bash script where I'm using the following to direct the stdout/stderr of every command to a file:

```
today=`/bin/date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`
exec 2> "/home/pi/stream_logs/$today.$RANDOM.txt"
exec 1>&2

[command 1
command 2
command 3
command 4
.... (many more commands)]
```

I'd like to redirect the stdout/stderr of command 2 to a DIFFERENT file, while keeping the stdout/stderr of every other command going to /home/pi/stream_logs/$today.$RANDOM.txt.

How can I override & redirect JUST the output of one command in this script to a separate file?

Comment: The commands are exactly sequential? Can `command2` happen before `command1`?

Comment: Command2 has to happen in the middle of a clump of commands

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this :

```
...
command 1
command 2 >path_of_secondary_output_file
command 3
...
```

Each command can be redirected individually.  When not redirected, the default is to connect to the stdout and stderr of the calling context (which is why `exec` has an effect on your commands), but that does not prevent redirecting individual commands.